# How do i fix this <a href> issue?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build my own website.I am new to html/css and I've been dealing with this problem for a while now . Whenever i try to create clickable text , it doesn't work. i want it to be clickable to open up another html file , but it's not working at all , any advice ?

Ok so it seems that the tabs work and lead to another html file only when css isn't linked to the main html i dont know why its like that .

```css
.Home {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  top: -140px;
  padding-left: 800px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Projects {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  top: -160px;
  padding-left: 900px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.About {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  top: -180px;
  padding-left: 1025px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home_css.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Home"> <a href="Home.html"><b>HOME</b></a></div>
  <div class="Projects"><a href="Projects.html"><b>PROJECTS</b></a></div>
  <div class="About"><a href="About.html"><b>ABOUT</b></a></div>

</body>

</html>
```

What i expected was for the tabs to be clickable and lead to another html file , but none of them are responding could it be that i did something wrong in the css ?

Comment: Unrealated to the "clickable" aspect, but your positioning is extremely weird. Why are you moving them off the top of the page with negative `top` and pushing extremely to the right with high padding left values?

Comment: Yes, what is the problem? Are you not able to see those tabs? Or, does click not responding?

Comment: Another top tip is to move all the replicated styles to a common class and used the "named" classes to provide the specific positioning: https://jsfiddle.net/jwxyoace/ .

Comment: @Jon P just so you know i have been doing html for 1 week now

Comment: @Ashokan Sivapragasam i can see them but i cant click on them

Comment: Post us the screenshot of your html page

Comment: Can you please provide code that replicates the issue. The code supplied basically works. See https://jsfiddle.net/z4nyr7v3/ . I've had to remove the `top` positioning so we can see the links. Please provide a [MCVE] . There is something else going on that you have not presented us with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `top:-140px` & **negative** values we cannot see div elements

*Also set `padding` values to low so no need to scroll page*

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home_css.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Home"> <a href="Home.html" target="_blank"><b>HOME</b></a></div>
    <div class="Projects"><a href="Projects.html" target="_blank"><b>PROJECTS</b></a></div>
    <div class="About"><a href="About.html target="_blank""><b>ABOUT</b></a></div>
  </body>
</html>

.Home a, .Home a:link {
      position: relative;
      font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
      color: black;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .Projects a, .Projects a:link {
      position: relative;
      font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
      color: black;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .About a, .About a:link {
      position: relative;
      font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
      color: black;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Please check the link
[Check here](https://jsfiddle.net/g9Lxjst6/)

Comment: This does actually work but 1 little issue , all the tabs open the same html file (contact.html)

Comment: You cannot able to open a page in window in mordern browsers. You can open in new tab by using  target="_blank" property.

Comment: But people using browser can make changes in browser property to open a page in new window or in new tabs if he want. Then target="_blank" property decides to open in new window or in new tabs depends on browser settings

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have another element above the links. Right-click on a faulty link, and select "Inspect element". This will open the development toolbar of your browser, with the element you right-clicked selected.

The selected element will either be the anchor, or it will be another element. If it's not the anchor, it means it's the element sitting above the anchor which prevents your click from going through.